# Debugging and troubleshooting Apache Karaf 3

Tags: json, rest, jersey, osgi, karaf

So I've OSGI-ified a war file. It still works in Tomcat. I have all the requisite fields in the manifest and the libraries are all embedded for now. I'll externalize them later. There are two which are not OSGI enabled. The war file has log4j2 embedded BTW. It will be removed later.

The war file in question is 3 simple Jersey based REST/JSON services.

It starts and goes to Active state but I can't hit it with SoapUI where I expect to find it.  The logs show it starting but that is all they show.

How can I squeeze more info out of Karaf so that I can properly figure out what is going on?

Is there something special I have to do in the Activator to get it to fire up?

Note: This is a simple REST / JSON service that wraps WURFL. By license, it's Open Source but it hasn't been released yet.

```
karaf@root()> bundle:headers MobileWURFL

MobileWURFL Maven Webapp (104)
-------------------------------
Manifest-Version = 1.0
Bnd-LastModified = 1395276484402
Archiver-Version = Plexus Archiver
Tool = Bnd-2.1.0.20130426-122213
Embed-Directory = WEB-INF/lib
Embedded-Artifacts = WEB-INF/lib/org.osgi.core-4.3.0.jar;g="org.osgi";a="org.osgi.core";v="4.3.0",WEB-INF/lib/org.osgi.compendium-1.4.0.jar;g="org.apache.felix";a="org.osgi.compend
ium";v="1.4.0",WEB-INF/lib/org.osgi.core-1.4.0.jar;g="org.apache.felix";a="org.osgi.core";v="1.4.0",WEB-INF/lib/javax.servlet-1.0.0.jar;g="org.apache.felix";a="javax.servlet";v="1.
0.0",WEB-INF/lib/org.osgi.foundation-1.2.0.jar;g="org.apache.felix";a="org.osgi.foundation";v="1.2.0",WEB-INF/lib/servlet-api-2.5.jar;g="javax.servlet";a="servlet-api";v="2.5",WEB-
INF/lib/log4j-api-2.0-rc1.jar;g="org.apache.logging.log4j";a="log4j-api";v="2.0-rc1",WEB-INF/lib/log4j-core-2.0-rc1.jar;g="org.apache.logging.log4j";a="log4j-core";v="2.0-rc1",WEB-
INF/lib/disruptor-3.0.1.jar;g="com.lmax";a="disruptor";v="3.0.1",WEB-INF/lib/commons-lang-2.6.jar;g="commons-lang";a="commons-lang";v="2.6",WEB-INF/lib/log4j-slf4j-impl-2.0-rc1.jar
;g="org.apache.logging.log4j";a="log4j-slf4j-impl";v="2.0-rc1",WEB-INF/lib/slf4j-api-1.7.5.jar;g="org.slf4j";a="slf4j-api";v="1.7.5",WEB-INF/lib/commons-collections-3.2.1.jar;g="co
mmons-collections";a="commons-collections";v="3.2.1",WEB-INF/lib/wurfl-1.5.1.jar;g="net.sourceforge.wurfl";a="wurfl";v="1.5.1",WEB-INF/lib/json-20140107.jar;g="org.json";a="json";v
="20140107",WEB-INF/lib/jersey-server-1.8.jar;g="com.sun.jersey";a="jersey-server";v="1.8",WEB-INF/lib/asm-3.1.jar;g="asm";a="asm";v="3.1",WEB-INF/lib/jersey-core-1.8.jar;g="com.su
n.jersey";a="jersey-core";v="1.8"
Built-By = Coder_Guy
Embed-Dependency = *;scope=compile|runtime
Embed-Transitive = true
Webapp-Context = MobileWURFL
Web-ContextPath = MobileWURFL
Build-Jdk = 1.7.0_51
Created-By = Apache Maven Bundle Plugin

Bundle-Name = MobileWURFL Maven Webapp
Bundle-SymbolicName = MobileWURFL
Bundle-Version = 0.0.1.SNAPSHOT
Bundle-ManifestVersion = 2
Bundle-ClassPath = .,WEB-INF/classes,WEB-INF/lib/org.osgi.core-4.3.0.jar,WEB-INF/lib/org.osgi.compendium-1.4.0.jar,WEB-INF/lib/org.osgi.core-1.4.0.jar,WEB-INF/lib/javax.servlet-1.0
.0.jar,WEB-INF/lib/org.osgi.foundation-1.2.0.jar,WEB-INF/lib/servlet-api-2.5.jar,WEB-INF/lib/log4j-api-2.0-rc1.jar,WEB-INF/lib/log4j-core-2.0-rc1.jar,WEB-INF/lib/disruptor-3.0.1.ja
r,WEB-INF/lib/commons-lang-2.6.jar,WEB-INF/lib/log4j-slf4j-impl-2.0-rc1.jar,WEB-INF/lib/slf4j-api-1.7.5.jar,WEB-INF/lib/commons-collections-3.2.1.jar,WEB-INF/lib/wurfl-1.5.1.jar,WE
B-INF/lib/json-20140107.jar,WEB-INF/lib/jersey-server-1.8.jar,WEB-INF/lib/asm-3.1.jar,WEB-INF/lib/jersey-core-1.8.jar
```

Answer (score 1):

As you are using a OSGi-fied war the war-extender of Pax Web will kick in. Therefore no activator needed. For debugging just start the karaf container with karaf debug, attach your debuger to port 8787. 
Depending on your embedded jars there might be an issue with those, for example a servlet.jar or similar will result in errors with deployment. Also possible the log4j2.jar could cause an issue. 
What's the result of bundle:header for this war?

With the command

```
web:list
```

you also receive the info of the state of the web bundle.

UPDATE:

It is right there in your Bundle-ClassPath. The servlet jar is not allowed to be in a WAR, per spec by the way. In OSGi it collides with the packages provided by Pax-Web. In a Tomcat, the servlet.jar is already loaded by the container therefore it does work, as First-Come-First-Serve is used by a classloader. With OSGi the first Servlet class is found inside the War and therefore the resolver doesn't use the one provided by Pax Web. It is essential that you remove that jar.
And I think adding those osgi jars doesn't help any either, this will most likely collide with the bundles provided by the container.
I strongly suggest using the maven-bundle-plugin to generate this war, so the imports are properly created. Or just neglect all OSGi meta information and deploy a standard WAR. If you use the following type URL:

```
webbundle:mvn:groupID/artifactID/version/war?Web-ContextPath=Mobile-WURFL
```

It will generate a proper OSGi Manifest for your war.

Comment: When I use http:list it is not listed but the web console is. :-/ Within the web console I can start it and it goes to Active and then I can stop it. 
I would give you the bundle:headers but it is quite long. There are no exports or imports.

Comment: I added the output of bundle:headers to the question.

Comment: The http:list command is for OSGi HttpServices and doesn't list any web contexts, it's the web:list command that will show you the state of your bundle. Most likely it'll show not-deployed.

Comment: karaf@root()> web:list
ID  | State       | Web-State   | Level | Web-ContextPath | Name
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
104 | Active      | Unknown     | 80    | /MobileWURFL   | MobileWURFL Maven Webapp (0.0.1.SNAPSHOT)
karaf@root()>

Comment: Looks like it's on port 80 but I still can't hit the service.

Comment: I did use the maven bundle plugin but the settings I used to embed the jars came from someone else's example of how to OSGI-ify a war file.  Thx for info about servlet api. Will try that. I think it is scoped as provided but got changed. I've created a much simpler war file to use for testing.

Comment: I'm very certain the servlet.jar is at least one of your issues ;)   And that's why it is in a Unknown Web-State, oh and it is not Port 80 it is on start-level 80, which is default for Custom Bundles in Karaf.